# Launch image does not disappear upon initial app launch but does thereafter

Tags: ios, trigger.io

I'm using Trigger.IO's toolkit to add the launch images. After doing so, the app fails to remove them from view after initially starting up the app. After hitting home and then going back to the app, the launch image disappears after launch.

The app isn't actually freezing after launch but just keeping the launch image at the forefront. I used a partially transparent image initially, and it appeared just to have a high z-index. I could use the app, but the launch image remained on screen over the top of everything.

Comment: did you wait a for sometime, sometimes debugging session is slow and takes time in startup?

Comment: I experience the same thing with Trigger.io on iOS, so its probably an issue with how they hide the launch image.

Comment: Yeah I've let it take it's time but the image stays up, @PatrickRudolph have you not found a solution either?

Comment: The only thing that seems to help for me is leaving the app (home button) and going back (as you already described). Anyway, I'm waiting for Trigger.io to fix this before pushing the app to the store right now.

Comment: Ok yeah we are in the same boat then. I just signed up for the Go Pro plan and asked them to check it out so I'm sure we'll be ready to ship soon!

Comment: @PatrickRudolph, do you by chance have a jailbroken iPhone? I've been debugging this one a jailbroken (iOs 5.1.1) and unjailbroken device (iOs 6) and it seems to respond much better on the unjailbroken one. May have something to do with https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap

Comment: No jailbroken devices, but I get the issue very frequently when starting the app on a (unjailbroken) iPhone 4S running iOS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of platform version v1.4.20 you can control the launchimage visibility (http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/release-notes.html#v1-4-20).

We've seen some instances of very early usage of the Forge APIs causing the launchimage not to show. In most cases, leaving the launchimage to hide itself manually is fine; if you're having problems or want more control over the launchimage, you can use forge.launchimage.hide.

Answer (score 1):

Very odd, the problem seems to have dissipated even though I have not attempted to address it directly considering it was merely a config file change.

I'll report back if the problem surfaces again, but all is well currently!

Answer (score -1):

Try add to use this code line

```
[window setRootViewController:mainController];
```

For full help, we need a some your codes

Comment: I should have clarified, I'm using Trigger.IO's toolkit to add the launch images